# Discord BOT.py - commands with diactritic doesn't work

Tags: python, discord, bots

Everytime i do command like:

/vyber - this works

/výber - this doesn't work

Is there any way for bot to ignore it, or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to remove accents (normalize) in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-normalize-in-a-python-unicode-string)

Answer (score 0):

You could decode the command-string using https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/ before comparing if I understand your question correctly.